# C++ STL containters to Glib conversion

Tags: c++, vector, glib, gvariant

I am trying to convert C++ code with STL containers to C and Glib.
Is that correct?

```
//vector<pair<int, int> > coordinates;
GArray coordinates((int, int));

//vector<vector<int> > adj_Matrix;
GArray adj_Matrix(GArray(int));

//vector<vector<int> > path_indices;
GArray path_indices(GArray(int));

//vector<pair<int, int> > connecting_indices;
GArray connecting_indices(GVariant(int,int));

//vector<vector<pair<int, int> > > points;
GArray points(GArray(GVariant(int,int)));
```

Comment: Did you try to compile this code?

Comment: yes. It compiles

Comment: Well it sure doesn't compile on g++... GArrays don't work the same as C++ template containers. I'd suggest taking a different approach and looking at examples for GArray.

Comment: Yes I mean it compiles with gcc. That is the idea to port code from C++ to C. Ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the target is C, then gcc is the right compiler to use. 
The only fact that the code compiles, says nothing about correctness, though. Maybe You missed a GVariant in the first row, or the definition is inconsistent. 
For clearness I would define `points` as `GArray` of `connecting_indices`, don't you? Anyway this doesn't look working C-code.